# How to create heat map with ArcGIS Runtime SDK for Windows Store apps

Tags: windows-8, dictionary, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro, arcgis

I have downloaded the [sample app of ArcGIS Runtime SDK for Windows Store apps](https://github.com/Esri/arcgis-samples-winstore). It has one sample called "Dynamic Layers" which has four option. The third option is "Unique Value Renderer" which seems to be heat map. But that sample uses data from REST API.

So I want to show heat map with my own data. My data contains some stats respective to each countries. According to that data I want to produce heat map, how can I do that ?

I want to do something like this.

[image: I want to do something like this.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[How to geoenrich applications with FeatureServices](http://kajanus.net/?p=362), Thanks to [Antti Kajanus](https://twitter.com/anttikajanus)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to publish your data to an ArcGIS Server service, and change the layer ServiceUri to point to your ArcGIS Server service.

What format do you have your data right now? (or from what type of service is it coming?)

Comment: The data is coming from SQLite database.